# Stripe Amex expiry date and cvc check

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe (version 2020-08-27) to charge customers in my mobile app. However, I've found that even I've entered the wrong expiry date and only 3/4 of cvc code was right of an amex card. The transaction will be successful and gone through.

I'm curious if that is the expected behavior of Stripe?

Two test I've did:

1. I've entered the correct cardholder's name, card number, expiry month + year, and 75% correct cvc (ie. the correct cvc is say 1234, I've entered 1034). The payment was successfully confirmed by Stripe.
2. I've entered the correct cardholder's name, card number, cvc, and a random expiry month + year. The payment was again successfully confirmed by Stripe.

Both of these example was using an Amex card.

Comment: An invalid piece of info about a card isn't automatically a failed charge. The networks will let Stripe know if any checks failed (and the network might block the charge itself), and Stripe exposes that to you as a merchant. You can use [Stripe Radar](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules) to act on that information automatically.

Comment: but I'm able to confirm that payment on Stripe, thus the transaction was successful